# Please help on file uploading using Flutter and Laravel

Tags: laravel, file, file-upload, flutter

I'm trying to upload images and other different types of files using Flutter mobile sdk and Laravel api. Here is my Flutter code :

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _image;

  Future getImageGallery() async {
    var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = imageFile;
    });
  }

  Future getImageCamera() async {
    var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = imageFile;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: _image == null
                  ? Text('No image selected')
                  : Image.file(_image),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.image),
              onPressed: getImageGallery,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              onPressed: getImageCamera,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
              onPressed: () {
                upload(_image);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Future upload(File imageFile) async {
    print(imageFile.path);
    var stream = http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
    var length = await imageFile.length();
    var uri = Uri.parse('https://api.tredlr.com/api/upload');
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
    var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile('image', stream, length,
        filename: basename(imageFile.path));
    request.files.add(multipartFile);
    var response = await request.send();

    print(response);
    print(response.stream);
    print(response.statusCode);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('uploaded');
    } else {
      print('not uploaded');
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my Laravel code :

```
$photo = $request->file("image");
$ext = $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
$fileName = rand(10000, 50000) . '.' .$ext;

$thumbSm = 'thumb_sm' . rand(10000, 50000) . '.' .$ext;

$image = Image::make($request->file('image'));
$image->save(base_path().'/public/'. $fileName);
$image->resize(120, 120);
$image->save(base_path().'/public/'. $thumbSm);
```

Comment: is this case solved ? I got this problem on my project too

Answer (score 1):

```
Future _test(File file) async {
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    file.existsSync();
    String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
        "image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,filename: fileName)
    });
    response = await dio.post("http://you ip address/api/route", data: formData);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but my server not getting the file showing null.

Comment: please check this link. https://pastebin.com/KVuYZV3d

Comment: I put my code upload image in flutter & laravel in this link, you can check https://pastebin.com/jdZzMhYd

Comment: Please inform me after inspecting this link, or you can contact with me via mail=> gurbanmyradownaguljahan@gmail.com

Comment: not working message "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null, " this is the error I'm getting